# What's the correct word division of this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning, word

I don't understand how I should understand this sentence word by word: 农夫过去一看. Without "guo4" everything is clear for me, since "qu4 yi2 kan4" means "to take a look".

But with "guo4" I don't know if it's "Nong2fu1 guo4qu4 yi2kan4" - **in this case I don't understand what "yi2" is doing here** - or "Nong2fu1 guo4 qu4yi2kan4" - **then I don't understand the role and meaning of "guo4"**. The whole sentence must mean "The farmer came to take a look"... The whole context:

> 老虎倒在了芦苇丛里。农夫过去一看，老虎前胸插着箭。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence describes a two parts action.

> "农夫过去一看" means "the farmer went over and took a look"

- 农夫 the farmer
- 过去 went over
- 一看 took a look

> 过 is a verb for "go over"  e.g. 过美国 (go over to The United States)
>
> 去 is the directional verb particle that indicates which direction the subject is going over
>
> "过去美国" (go over to The United States) is different from "过来美国" (come over to The United States); it is "农夫过去一看" (the farmer goes over and take a look), not "农夫过来一看" (the farmer comes over and take a look)

*一看 is a more literary style of saying 看看 or 看一看*

Note:

过去 (v): go over

过去 (n): past

Comment: A perfect answer - you explained both explained in details "过去" (I knew "过来", you made me realised it's exactly the same structure) and "一看" (I didn't know this formal way of softening actions). Now everything's clear. Thank you.